# Sentence ending で in じゃあ、僕はチーズバーガーで

Tags: grammar, particle-で

> はじめ：まずは腹ごしらえしておこうよ。
> たもつ：じゃあ、僕はチーズバーガーで。

Here is で in the second line part of a contraction Japanese use in their daily speech? If so what is the textbook version of the sentence?

Context: Hajime and Tamotsu are at a fast food restaurant, and the second line should be Tamotsu giving his order to the shop assistant. Thus I think で腹はらごしらえする may not be the best fit for the context...

Answer (score 3):

As the dialog gives us no other clues what たもつ really had in his mind, I think 「僕はチーズバーガーで[腹]{はら}ごしらえする／腹ごしらえしておく」 would be the most logical expansion.

Answer (score 1):

> じゃあ、僕はチーズバーガーで。

in textbook version would look like:

> それでは、僕はチーズバーガーにします。

In this case 「で」 expresses his choice.