# Sentence-ending で in a formal context

Tags: particles

I am aware that [there is another question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28317/sentence-ending-%E3%81%A7) that talks about sentence-ending で. But the example in that question is in an informal setting.

I have an example of a sentence-ending で in a [newspaper headline](https://www.sankei.com/economy/news/181127/ecn1811270021-n1.html):

> カウチシート初導入 全日空がＡ３８０型機就航 来年５月に成田発着で

I know what the sentence means, and I am guessing the ending で is somehow still a variation of します, as it was explained in the answer to the [other question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28317/sentence-ending-%E3%81%A7). Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newspaper headlines, the most important information is placed at the top, and particles and verb phrases are often left out.
So the で in your example is a normal particle で, rather than a sentence-ending で. You can rearrange the word order and read it this way...

> 来年５月に、成田発着(便)で、全日空がＡ３８０型機**を**就航**して**、カウチシート**を**初(めて)導入**します**。

For more about "headline grammar", see these threads:

- [what is the name of the abbreviated writing style used in newspapers?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14512/9831)
- [why does the following title end "...守られる" and not "守られている"? just to save space?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23785/9831)
- [What form is あり?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/35942/9831)